# Deleting a branch in a shallow clone

Tags: git

I am working in a shallow clone of a git repository. Since the shallow clone only lists one remote tracking branch in the .git/config file, to get new remote branches I need to add them explicitly. For example

```
git clone --depth 1 <remote-url>
git remote set-branches --add origin <branch-name>
git fetch --depth 1 origin <branch-name>
git checkout <branch-name>
```

Later if I delete the branch

```
git checkout master
git branch --delete <branch-name>
```

and push the deletion to the remote

```
git push --delete origin <branch-name>
```

I have a problem. When I `pull` or `fetch` I get the error message

> fatal: Couldn't find remote ref <branch-name>

There is no `--remove` option corresponding to `git remote set-branches --add` so how do I remove the missing branch? Is it a matter of editing the .git/config file to remove the line

```
fetch = +refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>
```

or is there a less hidden way to do it? I am surprised that pushing the branch deletion did not prune the fetch line.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the exact situation, so not sure... but does `git branch --unset-upstream <branch-name>` work?

Comment: Sadly not - that reports `fatal: Branch '<branch-name>' has no upstream information`. I'll try it before the deletion though and see if that helps

Comment: Yeah, I finally reproduced the original error (found a step I'd missed) and see that it isn't fixed quite that easily.  I'll play around a bit and let you know what I find.

Comment: Are there many other branches that you're tracking?

Comment: There might be, but in fact there are currently only three: master and two task branches

Comment: Tentative answer below, I'll look for something better.  This is strange to me, why this information can get orphaned like this.  We're in a part of git I don't know a lot about, but I suspect it could be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Option 1: Avoid the Problem?*

The problem can be avoided if you don't explicitly tell git what branches you want it to fetch.  (But if you need to fetch only a selected set of branches, probably better skip to option 2.)  When you create the clone you can say you want all the branches

```
git clone --depth=1 --no-single-branch ...
```

Or if you already cloned and want to get the rest of the branches: From your instructions, instead of

```
git remote set-branches --add origin <branch-name>
```

which configures fetch to look for a specific branch, you could

```
git config --unset remote.origin.fetch
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git fetch --depth=1
```

Deleting a branch (locally and remotely) no longer causes a problem.

(You may be able to use a more selective pattern, but in cases where you don't want "everything" it may be bet to pick and choose individual branches.)

If you already have the repository and added a few branches the way you describe above, config commands similar to what I've listed should "repair" it.  (Just replace `--unset` with `--unset-all` in the first command.)

*Option 2: Fix the problem*

But if you do need your config to list individual branches, you can handle the delete in one of these ways:

*You can use `git config`* to directly remove the setting without manually editing any files.

```
git config --unset remote.origin.fetch <branch-name>
```

Beware that `<branch-name>` is interpreted as a regex, and if it matches multiple values then it won't work.  So if you get a warning about multiple matching values, you'd have to do something like

```
git config --unset remote.origin.fetch origin.<branch-name>$
```

*Or you can use `git remote set-branches`*:

While there isn't an explicit `git remote set-branches --remove` or anything of that sort, you can use `set-branches` *without* the `--add` flag to reset the list of remote branches entirely.  If you don't have too many other branches, this would work.  For example, given only what's shown above you could do

```
git remote set-branches origin master
```

But if you've added a bunch of other branches, you'd have to list them too or lose them.

```
git remote set-branches origin master branch1 branch2 branch3 ...
```

You could automate the process of getting the branch list

```
git branch | sed s/'\* '// | xargs git remote set-branches origin
```

But that would have an issue if any of the local branches are not, in fact, meant to track origin.

Comment: I don't like this one as you'd need to construct the list of branches. It looks *harder* than editing the .git/config file

Comment: Depends what you mean "easy".  If you want to bypass the porcelain and manually edit files, there may be less steps.  On the other hand, the porcelain protects you from corrupting your repo (generally).  So if you don't like it, don't use it; like I said I'm looking for something better.  But also note, constructing a branch list isn't that *hard* - just possibly tedious.  Regardless, you asked about less hidden ways to do it.  So far, that's one.

Comment: It's also occurred to me that we could write a bash one-liner that gets the results of `git branch` and concatenates them into `git remote set-branches`. Not sure if that's cheating, but could work well

Comment: Updated to show how to do it with `git config`.  That's better, but I still feel like something's off that we'd have to use a command like that.  (And it's only a half step better than manually editing the config file.)

Comment: Ok, one last approach.  In the words of Mr. Miyagi: best block, no be there

Comment: Not so fast. How about this: `git branch | sed s/'\* '// | xargs git remote set-branches origin ` Then I'd only lose remote tracking branches that I've never checked out.

Comment: The option you provide with '*' in is dangerous since it fetches all remote branch tips (I think). I need to avoid that. I only want to fetch the tip of branches that have some files etc removed

Comment: Yes, that probably would automate the process of getting the branch list if you want to use the first approach (well... the *last* one in the answer's current form).  It may have an issue if any of the local branches are not, in fact, meant to track origin.  I think if I were doing it, I'd first look at whether I could get by with tracking using wildcards (e.g. with `--no-single-branch`), and if not I'd use git config to remove broken fetch settings if possible. While the `set-branches` idea was the first solution I came across, I don't know that it's the best

Comment: You've confused "dangerous" with "may not meet my needs".  Again, that's why I've provided multiple options.

Comment: One last point: are the files you're avoiding things that should be scrubbed from the origin repository altogether?  (If so, you might look at BFG Repo Cleaner.  But beware, if you have any workflows that depend on existing commit hashes, then BFG could cause you trouble.)